# naming states in angularjs ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

instead of using ng.router i am switching to ui.router in my angularjs application.

I came across a problem about state names in config. When I use '.' character in state name, routing doesn't work. Code I gave below doesn't route to 'views/subcategories.html' when I enter "localhost/#/categories/5" in my browser url.

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('categories',
        {
            url:'/categories',
            controller:'CategoriesController',
            templateUrl:'views/categories.html'
        })
    .state('sub.categories',{
            url:'/categories/:subID',
            controller: 'SubCategoriesController',
            templateUrl:'views/subcategories.html'
    });
```

However when I use 'subcategories' instead of 'sub.categories' it works. I am asking this question because I saw state names with '.' in a lot of tutorials about ui.router. Do I miss some detail here?

Answer (score 3):

with dot syntax in name of states, you can a nested states. The nested state, inherit params and urls from parent state.

First, you need start the name of nested state, with parent state:

```
'categories.sub' // instead 'sub.categories'
```

Then, to localhost/#/categories/5, set your nested state like below:

```
$stateProvider
.state('categories',
    {
        url:'/categories',
        controller:'CategoriesController',
        templateUrl:'views/categories.html'
    })
.state('categories.sub',{
        url:'/:subID',
        controller: 'SubCategoriesController',
        templateUrl:'views/subcategories.html'
});
```

Note, the state 'categories.sub', in url, dont need '/categories', because this is inherit from parent state 'categories'

Answer (score 0):

In ui-router, periods are used to indicate nested states.

Using `sub.categories` would make the `categories` state a child of the `sub` state.

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views)